# How to check the timestamp of a command from command history in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I was wondering is it possible to check the timestamp of a command in Matlab? If I look at the command history I can see the timestamps separating the commands of different dates for example:

[image]

But is it possible to get the timestamp of a particular command? =)

Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you are looking for is not native to MATLAB.

BUT using [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26471) custom `Command Prompt` you can achieve it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I use the custom prompt above. Personally, I prefer `setPrompt('[''['',datestr(now, ''HH:MM:SS''), ''] >> '']')` which becomes `[01:06:47] >>`.

Answer (score 2):

Did you ask Google before posting? [4-th result](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/command-history.html) says it's all written in ˙history.m`

This [link](http://thedaneshproject.com/posts/history-command-with-time-stamp/) explains that you can check history by typing `history` in the command line. By default this won't get you timestamps. But setting the output format:

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT=' %F %T '
```

your `history` will give you timestamps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately there were no timestamps in my history.m I had checked that one already :(

Answer (score 1):

As an update to @dedek-mraz's answer, and for future reference: I have located the file `History.xml` in `%appdata%\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2018a`(Windows 10), which you can open and search by your favorite text editor.
Then I went to Command History in Matlab GUI and scrolled backwards to the respective day. Not very elegant, but it worked.